# Python CSV Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Hello all I keep getting this error while making a small program to sort large CSV files out, below is my code and error, what am I doing wrong?

```
if selection:
        for stuff in stuffs:

            try:
                textFile = open("output.txt",'w')
                mycsv = csv.reader(open(stuff))
                d_reader = csv.DictReader(mycsv)
                headers = d_reader.fieldnames <-- Error happens here
                if selection in headers:
                    placeInList = headers.index(selection)

                    #placeInList = selection.index(selection)
                    for selection in tqdm(mycsv, desc='Extracting column values...', leave = True):
                        textFile.write(str(selection[int(placeInList)])+'\n')
                    print 'Done!'
                    textFile.close()
                    sys.exit()
            except IOError:
                print 'No CSV file present in directory'
                sys.exit()
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "postcodeExtractor.py", line 27, in <module> headers = d_reader.fieldnames 
File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames self._fieldnames = self.reader.next() 
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, list found
```

Comment: can you show us the error log?

Comment: on what line is it showing this error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postcodeExtractor.py", line 27, in <module>
    headers = d_reader.fieldnames
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, list found

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
mycsv = csv.reader(open(stuff))
d_reader = csv.DictReader(mycsv)
```

you want

```
d_reader = csv.DictReader(open(stuff))
```

the first line is the problem.

Comment: sorry about that.  Is `stuff` a filepath?